# Should one put future employment on one's resume?

Tags: professionalism, resume, job-search

Should one put future employment on one's resume, e.g. a job one will start in a month or two months?

Comment: Why would you need a resume if you already have a future job? Additionally what is to stop someone from lying on such a document? Bad idea to my mind.

Comment: Perhaps if it's a temporary/seasonal position but relevant to one's career, e.g. teaching assistant for a CS course?

Comment: What is the upside for the potential other employer to know that you intend to be an assistant for a CS course as isn't there a chance that the offer could be withdrawn?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Should one put future employment on one's resume

**No.** Your resume should reflect your knowledge and your experience. You should avoid including anything that you haven't yet experienced.

It should include actual jobs you have held - not jobs you expect to hold, jobs you hope you will hold, or jobs you wish you held.

You can always revise it in a month or two once your potential job actually comes to fruition.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is maybe.

Why do people have resumes? To find jobs, and to help their company win contracts. Every company I have worked for has required me to maintain a resume that they can submit to potential customers to prove the quality of their employees.

If you have an item that is in the future, it may make sense to include it. Some examples:

- Selected for a graduate school.
- Awaiting graduation date for a completed set of courses.
- Having been selected for an internship or training program.
- Having been awarded a grant for a research project.
- Having been selected for a program that only takes place a few times a year or requires a long training period.

Answer (score 1):

I do think there needs to be some clarification here as to why you'd need to put your resume out if you have a job that is upcoming?

Now should you put a job that you'll have in the future? No. Your resume should be about skills that you already have that relate to the position you're applying for. Since you never acquire any skills since the job is upcoming, it wouldn't make sense to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

If you have a job that will start in a month or two, why are you looking for a job? If you are looking for a job, how do you think that would look on your resume? In the best case it will confuse the company you're applying to, and at best they will think you will only be staying with them for a month or two. Either way, your resume would be passed up.

If you're not looking for a new job, then why are you updating your resume right now? I could see updating it after you start, but right now you don't even know what you'll be doing really.