# Is it OK to include future achievements on my CV?

Tags: resume

I am accepted to give a talk in March, but I need to send my CV now. Is it accepted/morally OK to include it on the CV with appropriate text that this talk is only about to happen?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you consider writing in CV the achievement as it is right now: "was accepted to give a talk"? See also: [Should one put future employment on one's resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/37033/168)

Comment: Gnat's comment is basically the answer - if it's an achievement, it's *by definition* in the past.

Comment: What if they cancelled your talk at the last minute - after you told everyone and their brother that you were going to give that talk? On the other hand, I'd definitely put down my expected date of graduation from MIT, Caltech or Stanford down. Your talk may mean much to you - how much it means to others is an open question.

Answer (score 9):

Your CV describes what you **have** done. Not what you have plans to do in the future.

Having a paper accepted for publication by a journal is an achievement, because it's an end goal (the paper is written to be published by a journal).

Having a proposal to give a talk in the future is not an achievement, it is a step along the path to the end goal of giving that talk (you prepare the talk so that you can give it, not so that you can be accepted to give it). Any number of things could happen in the next 6 weeks stopping you from completing it.

Comment: In some cases getting accepted to give a talk is competitive, and requires submission of at least an abstract. So in a real sense, the achievement is getting the talk accepted, rather than giving it, which will now follow automatically.

Answer (score 9):

While I would *not* put this on a CV, if I wanted them to take into account that I needed to be in Seattle on April27-30 for the XYZ conference where I am giving a talk on EFG, I would put that in the cover letter and mention it in the negotiations if you get an offer. (You do want the time off, right? Maybe even have your way there paid if the conference isn't paying your travel expenses?)

By putting it in the cover letter, you are letting them know you have an obligation to attend to on a date after you would be working for them and letting them know that you are accepted as a speaker which is certainly a plus. This gives you a chance to still impress them that you have been accepted without adding it to your CV until it actually happens.